# Exceptions within unittests are not caught by the Python debugger

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, pdb

Consider a `unittest` suite like this:

```
import unittest

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_set_trace(self):
        raise Exception

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestClass)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

When I put the following in the script and run it like so: `python -m pdb tmp.py` I would expect the Python debugger to catch the exception and bring me inside the `test_set_trace` method, however `unittest` catches the exception and hides it from `pdb` like so:

```
$ python -m pdb tmp.py
> tmp.py(1)<module>()
-> import unittest
(Pdb) c
test_set_trace (__main__.TestClass) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: test_set_trace (__main__.TestClass)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 5, in test_set_trace
    raise Exception
Exception

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
The program finished and will be restarted
> tmp.py(1)<module>()
-> import unittest
(Pdb)
```

This is annoying when writing my tests as I need to go into the testing code and specify `pdb.set_trace()` manually, then step to the frame that contains the actual bug. Does anyone know of a workaround? Putting an explicit `import pdb` inside the testing code doesn't help, even if I put the import statement within the actual offending method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`TestSuite.debug`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestSuite.debug).

> **debug()**
>
> Run the tests associated with this suite without collecting
>   the result. This allows exceptions raised by the test to be propagated
>   to the caller and can be used to support running tests under a
>   debugger.

---

Replace following line:

```
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

with:

```
suite.debug()
```